# При вылете сервера, приложение вылетает с ошибкой

Tags: java, android, socket.io

Как только я выключаю сервер, в клиенте android мне вылетает вот такая ошибка.

```
12-05 13:49:30.399 13954-14763/ru.exodus.lorehub E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: EventThread
                                                               Process: ru.exodus.lorehub, PID: 13954
                                                               io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
                                                                   at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
                                                                   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableCreate$Emitter.onError(CompletableCreate.java:77)
                                                                   at ru.themax.rxsocket.RxSocket.lambda$null$1(RxSocket.java:47)
                                                                   at ru.themax.rxsocket.RxSocket$$Lambda$11.call(Unknown Source)
                                                                   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter$OnceListener.call(Emitter.java:164)
                                                                   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                   at io.socket.client.Socket.access$601(Socket.java:24)
                                                                   at io.socket.client.Socket$5.run(Socket.java:186)
                                                                   at io.socket.thread.EventThread.exec(EventThread.java:55)
                                                                   at io.socket.client.Socket.emit(Socket.java:182)
                                                                   at io.socket.client.Manager.emitAll(Manager.java:166)
                                                                   at io.socket.client.Manager.access$600(Manager.java:30)
                                                                   at io.socket.client.Manager$1$3.call(Manager.java:306)
                                                                   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onError(Socket.java:820)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$900(Socket.java:36)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$4.call(Socket.java:340)
                                                                   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onError(Transport.java:64)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR.access$100(PollingXHR.java:26)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$6$1.run(PollingXHR.java:140)
                                                                   at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                Caused by: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onError(Transport.java:63)
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR.access$100(PollingXHR.java:26) 
                                                                   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$6$1.run(PollingXHR.java:140) 
                                                                   at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80) 
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /46.173.218.234:80
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:225)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:149)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:195)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
                                                                   at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
                                                                   at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /46.173.218.234 (port 80) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
                                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:234)
                                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
                                                                   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
                                                                   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
                                                                   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
                                                                at java.net.Sock
```

**Подключение к сокету я делают вот таким образом:**

```
 public void authServer(){
    socket.connect()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(() -> {
            listenForErrors(); //Вот здесь запускаю метод отлавливания
            view.showAuthFragment();
        }, throwable -> {
            view.showErrorFragment(null);
            throwable.printStackTrace();

        });
}
```

**Я пытаюсь ее поймать вот таким способом:**

```
private void listenForErrors(){
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(objects -> {
                        view.showError("Ошибка соединения!");
                        view.showErrorFragment(null);
                        socket.off(Socket.EVENT_ERROR);
                        socket.disconnect();
                    });

}
```

Это улучшенная библиотека сокетов с поддержкой RxJava.
Ошибка вылетает не в коде, а где-то внутри, поэтому обычным try - catch я не могу ее словить, как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена таким образом:

```
RxSocket provideSocket(){
    IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
    options.transports = new String[]{"websocket"};
    options.reconnection = false;
    options.forceNew = false;
    return new RxSocket(Constants.URL, options);
}
```

Нужно было при инициализации добавить настройку `reconnection = false;`

Comment: А если выключить сервер и запустить приложение?

Comment: В этом случае проблемы не было до вопроса.